# Within a found example code, what is the surprising syntax in an arrow function callback of Array.prototype.find for?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, return-value

I found the following example code, and I want to figure out what it does.

```
projects.find( p => p.value === 'jquery-ui' && ( p.desc = 'your value', true ) );
```

What is the last `true` from `( p.desc = 'your value', true )` for? I know that `find` should return just the first matching array item but I see, with the use of the provided example code, it did not only find the object but it did also change it.

Comment: it is called Comma_Operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: It is assigning the desc with `your value` and then returning `true`.

Comment: This code is so confusing because it tries to be overly smart. It does not actually just find an item, which is covered by the condition `p.value === 'jquery-ui'`, in addition it also assigns a value to the found item's `desc` property and on top it uses the comma operator for returning a final `true` value in order to satisfy the already met condition again. Thus said, a clean implementation should/might more look like this one ... `projects.find(p => p.value === 'jquery-ui')?.desc = 'your value';`

Answer (score 4):

This is actually quite terrible code. ಠ_ಠ

First, the comma operator evaluates all its operands and returns the last one. I.e., `p.desc = 'your value', true` assigns `'your value'` to `p.desc` and returns `true`. This is chained to the `p.value === 'jquery-ui'` check, so only executes when that expression is `true`. The entire thing is in a `find`, which iterates over all items until it finds an item where the callback function returns `true`.

In other words, it's using `Array.prototype.find` to iterate over all the array entries, and when it finds an entry whose `.value` is `'jquery-ui'`, it updates that entry by setting `.desc`, then ends the `find` iteration by returning `true`.

Which is actually quite clever, but:

1. Introduces a *side effect* into what should be a pure test callback function and
2. leads to questions like this because it's unnecessarily clever and hard to comprehend at first sight.

Comment: Frankly, I do not fully understand the difference when not using `, true`. Because the result is the same.

Comment: Indeed, if `'your value'` is truthy, the `, true` is actually unnecessary. Maybe there's a case where it may be falsey.

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL only matters if `'your value'` can vary. This string is truthy but it's possible it's just copy-pasted code (code reuse!). Alternatively, perhaps this is an example code and the real one has `(p.desc = value, true)`

Comment: @deceze ... you said it, and if the one whoever was writing this code was a real Ninja-developer the code is supposed to look like this ... `projects.find(p => (p.value === 'jquery-ui') && !!(p.desc = 'your value'))`

Comment: @PeterSeliger if it is `'your value'`, the `!!` is not required. Just `p.desc = 'your value'` expression returns `'your value'` which is truthy. `, true` is only needed when the assignment is being done with a falsy value. Like `p.desc = ''` or `p.desc = null`

Comment: @Peter Oh my, the superfluous-cast-to-bool ninjutsu! 

Comment: @adiga ... do you understand a developer's irony/sarcasm (hint ... I was using *Ninja*)? ... *deceze* did.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to find the first object with `p.value === 'jquery-ui'` and update its  `desc`  property to `'your value'`.

It's equivalent to:

```
const found = projects.find(p => p.value === 'jquery-ui');

if (found)
  found.desc = 'your value'
```

- First, it checks the  `p.value === 'jquery-ui'` condition. If it returns false, `&&` will short-circuit and will not check the second block. It goes over to the next object in the array.
- If `p.value === 'jquery-ui'` is true for some object in the array, `&&` will execute the second expression `( p.desc = 'your value', true )`. This uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It evaluates each expression within () and returns the final value. It assigns a new value to the found object and returns `true`. This is done to short-circuit the `find` call so that it stops running this callback on any more objects in the array.
- The comma operator is ONLY required if `'your value'` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). In your case, it's a non-empty string. It is redundant and no different to using

  ```
   p.value === 'jquery-ui' && p.desc = 'your value'
  ```